# Show that if $f:R\rightarrow R$ is continuous and $k=\{x\in R: f(x) = 0\}$, then $K$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

Looking for a hint / help with the following problem:

A set $K$ is closed if and only if for all sequences $(x_n)$ in $K$, if $(x_n)$ converges to $l$ then $l$ is an element of $K$.  Use this result to show that if $f:R\rightarrow R$ is continuous, and $k=\{x \in R: f(x) = 0\}$, then K is closed.

Trying to go down a road where I assume a sequence $(x_n)$ that converges to $l$ and then, since the function is continuous I know that $lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x)   $ is the same as $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f (x_n)$  .  Since $f$ is continuous this would be the same as $f(c)$.  Of course then the set $K$ would only be made up of the $"c"$s where $f(c) = 0$.  Therefore all of the sequences that are $(x_n)$ converges to a value $l$ that is an element of $K$.  Hence $K$ is closed.

Does this make sense?  Am I on the right track?

Comment: This makes very vague sense. You could be a little more mathematical, but I think you have the right idea.

Comment: does R mean real numbers with the standard toplogy? . if so , take the inverse image of 0 which is closed in R, and due to continuity K is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Approach #1: Limit Points

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $K$ converging to $l$. Using the continuity of $f$,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \right) = f(l).$$

However, $f(x_n) = 0$ for all $n$, thus $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = 0$ (constant sequence). Again using the continuity of $f$, we have that $f(l) = 0$ so $l \in K$ as well. Therefore $K$ is closed as it contains all of its limit points.

#### Approach #2: Point-Set Topology

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be equipped with the standard topology. Since $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, the preimage of an open set is open. Thus $f^{-1} ( \mathbb{R} \setminus 0)$ is open and is equal to the complement of $K= f^{-1}(0)$. Since the complement of $K$ is open, we have that $K$ is closed.

Comment: Approach #1 was the road I was going down and is really close to what I have written down as an answer.  Appreciate the help and the response.